# Cannot Use PrepareForSegue Back to Back

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have been trying to figure out why this does not work but have had no luck:

I am making an IOS app in Xcode and have it set up as so: I first segue from **ViewControllerA** (LoginViewController) to **ViewControllerB** (HomeViewController). During this segue I pass a UIImage and a UILabel to be shown in ViewControllerB. Once this occurs, I wanted to set up another prepareForSegue to go to **ViewControllerC** (ProfileViewController) and pass this same data again. However, each time I try to do so, the app gets all glitchy and crashes or freezes. I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

I was hoping that there was a way I don't have to do a prepareForSegue each time I want to pass data - something like a Global Variable or a Singleton. **BUT** I am trying to avoid using these two options as I have read plenty of times that these options are dangerous and should not really be used. *If* either of these ways is appropriate here then by all means let me know and that will be the end of it.

For the mean time, I wanted to see if anyone could help me understand as to why this error keeps happening. Here is my code for the ViewControllerA.m:

**LoginViewController.m**

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface LoginViewController ()

- (void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize profPicture;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.loggedinwallpaper.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.FBlogout.hidden = shouldHide;
}


-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{

    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){


        self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
        self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
        self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];

        // Create Facebook Profile Picture from User ID url
        NSString *pic_link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=300&height=300", user.objectID];
        NSURL *pic_url = [NSURL URLWithString:pic_link];
        profPicture = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pic_url]];

        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Main Thread : UI Updates
//            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//            UIViewController *homeViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
//            [self performSelector:@selector(prepareForSegue:sender:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0 ];
//            [self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

            //[_invisible                         sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMap" sender:self];

       //});
    //});
}


-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    HomeViewController *homeviewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    homeviewController.homepic = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    homeviewController.homepic = profPicture;
    homeviewController.username = self.lblUsername;
}


@end
```

Now here is my ViewControllerB code:

**HomeViewController.m**

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize homeviewpic, homepic, sendpic, homeViewUsername, username;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //----------Profile Picture---------------------------------------
    // Determine the context of where to set image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.homeviewpic.frame.size);
    [homepic drawInRect:self.homeviewpic.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Create subview to be added
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // Add subview
    [self.homeviewpic addSubview:backgroundView];
    [self.homeviewpic setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    sendpic = homepic;



    //----------Username-----------------------------------------------
    //homeViewUsername.text = username.text;



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    self.homeViewUsername.text = self.username.text;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//-----------------------------Screenshot of background void method--------------------------------
- (UIImage *) screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#pragma mark - Navigation

 //In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ProfileViewController *PVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    //PVC.profPic = sendpic;
    //PVC.profileViewUsername = username;
}


@end
```

Just for now I have commented out the lines in the prepareForSegue - these lines were the source of the issue. If someone could please help explain and try to provide a solution I would be very appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you performing segue in view controller B?

Comment: with a button. i had it coded but i took it out as it was not working either

Comment: @KakshilShah i just keeps crashing/freezing every time I try and introduce a new data transfer setup through prepareForSegue. Im not sure how to get around this since i need this data to be passed to the next VC..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to present two viewcontrollers in your dispatch_async.
presentViewController and performSegueWithIdentifier do the same thing. You have to put some condition so one of them is called in your dispatch_async method. Trying to present two viewcontrollers will crash.

Comment: i have everything commented except for the  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMap" sender:self];. If that's the case shouldnt that only be one segue?

Comment: Your app freezing/crashing with that commented code as well?

Comment: yea. im not sure why it is freezing. it bugs out when I uncomment the couple of lines in prepareForSegue in HomeViewController. It must not want me sharing the same piece of data twice. i'm at a loss

Comment: try moving homeviewController.homepic = [[UIImage alloc] init]; in viewDidLoad

Comment: that didnt work at all :\ since it doesnt know about the HomeViewcontroller in the ViewDidLoad method whatsoever